# How to check the compiler version in Qt .pro file?

Tags: linux, qt

I want to build a Qt project using either GCC or an ARM compiler. In either environment I have to link different libraries.

How I can check if the current compiler is Linux's g++ and `CROSS_COMPILE` is `'arm-cortexa9neont-linux-gnueabi-'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Platform Scope](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-language.html#platform-scope-values) built in to QMake to set up the build differently depending on platform.

It's based on the mkspec's shipped with Qt and can be found in

> [Where Qt's installed]/mkspecs

So in your case I guess it'll look something like this:

```
linux-arm-gnueabi {
    //ARM stuff here
}
```

**Please note** that I have not tested this. I've only read what's in the documentation I have linked to.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know only type of processor, you can use [Q_PROCESSOR_ARM](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtglobal.html#Q_PROCESSOR_ARM) macro.